# Cannot extend the size of a partition:

Tags: debian, partition

I have a problem while trying to extend the size of one of the partitions that i found on a old VM on the cloud, this is the output of the `lsblk` so you can have an idea on it:

enter code here

```
root@Desktop:~# lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1                   8:1    0  1,9G  0 part /
├─sda2                   8:2    0    1K  0 part
└─sda5                   8:5    0 18,1G  0 part
  ├─vg_root-lv_swap    254:0    0  1,9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg_root-lv_usr     254:1    0  4,8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─vg_root-lv_home    254:2    0  244M  0 lvm  /home
  ├─vg_root-lv_opt     254:3    0  488M  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─vg_root-lv_XXXXXXX 254:4    0  244M  0 lvm  /XXXXXXX
  ├─vg_root-lv_tmp     254:5    0  1,4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─vg_root-lv_var     254:6    0  976M  0 lvm  /var
  └─vg_root-lv_varlog  254:7    0  976M  0 lvm  /var/log
sdb                      8:16   0   20G  0 disk
sdc                      8:32   0   20G  0 disk
sr0                     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

The output of `df -h` is as follow:

```
root@Desktop# df -h
file systel                    Size      Used  Free  Used%  Monted on
/dev/sda1                        1,9G    800M  976M  46%    /
udev                              10M       0   10M   0%    /dev
tmpfs                            1,6G     77M  1,5G   5%    /run
/dev/dm-1                        4,6G    654M  3,7G  15%    /usr
tmpfs                            4,0G       0  4,0G   0%    /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5,0M       0  5,0M   0%    /run/lock
tmpfs                            4,0G       0  4,0G   0%    /sys/fs/YYYYYY
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_XXXXXXXX  233M    2,1M  215M   1%    /XXXXXXX
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_opt       465M     72M  365M  17%    /opt
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_home      233M    2,1M  215M   1%    /home
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_tmp       1,4G    2,2M  1,3G   1%    /tmp
[[/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_var       945M    928M     0 100%    /var]]
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_varlog    945M     29M  852M   4%    /var/log
```

The partition between the  `[[ ]]` is the one i am aiming to extend ? is there any way to shrink the other partitions and make it bigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unmount the filesystems before you do this e.g. by switching to emergency mode (or booting into it):

```
umount /var/log
umount /var/
lvresize --resizefs --size -500G vg_root/lv_var
lvresize --resizefs --size +500G vg_root/lv_varlog
```

Comment: Note that not all filesystems can be shrunk, even when unmounted. For example, you can shrink an *ext4* filesystem, but not an *XFS*. This is not a principal limitation: the necessary tool hasn't been created yet. On the other hand, dump and restore works any time, but needs extra storage.

Comment: @FerencWágner I am well aware of that (it's why I do not use XFS or ZFS) but at first I offer a simple solution which works in the typical case.